# How to connect MySQL from VC++ on MS Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: mysql, database, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

How to connect with MySQL from Visual C++ Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 ? I tried googling and found solutions all of which ended with fatal errors like linker errors,... etc. Please explain (or provide a link) step by step, including prerequisites (with links) and all details. I don't need any query examples.. just connecting to MySQL. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me (I am using xampp):

1. Open a C++ project (with precompiled header)
2. Change it from Debug to Release.
3. Install complete mysql (if you
   install complete mysql, a C
   connector will also be installed as a
   include and lib file, which is not
   installed in typical installation)
4. copy `mysql/include`  to `xampp/mysql`
5. `project > project properties > configuration properties > c++ > general > additional include
   directory`  --> `C:/xmapp/mysql/include`.
6. `Project > add existing item > lidmysql.lib` (it’s found in
   `mysql/lib/opt`.)
7. Copy `libmysql.dll` to `c:\windows`.
   Alternativly we can copy it to the
   project’s folder or we can set path
   environment variable. But we only
   tested it copy to `c:\windows`

Answer (score 2):

[MySQL++](http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/) supports VC++ 2008, and comes with specific documentation on how to set up your project to avoid the link errors you're seeing.

*Disclosure: I'm MySQL++'s maintainer*